# Wrong environmental variable path ending in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, encoding, escaping

I'm working with Autodesk FBX files, so I've added an environmental variable to the system table pointing to the FBX SDK intallation folder in an equivalent manner to the DirectX standard env. variable, set as follows:

```
FBXSDK_DIR = C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2016.1.2\
```

And it works just fine, at least until I've decided to download a [VS2013 solution written in Japanes](https://github.com/shaderjp/FBXLoader2015forDX11)e, and suddenly the compiler complains about inclusions; checking better, IntelliSense now is saying my environmental variable, as appearing on the list of included paths, is this:

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2016.1.2"
```

That causes the inclusion to be:

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2016.1.2"include
```

...instead of:

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2016.1.2\include
```

...thus throwing a legitimate error.

Now obviously, the first thing that popped into my mind is it has something to do with encoding and escaping characters, however I have no idea if I can change a setting to solve it or more complicated stuff. Is there any possibility for me to fix this? Without remaking the solution from scratch, that is.

---

EDIT: Here's something funny; if I write in `$(FBXSDK_DIR)""` in the *Include Directories*, IntelliSense will say the two paths (the inclusions always appear twice in the list for some reason) are now resolved to:

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2016.1.2\include"\"\"
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2016.1.2\include""""
```

And if I write in `$(FBXSDK_DIR)""""` it will be:

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2016.1.2\include"\"\"\"\"
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2016.1.2\include""""""
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are confusing the character `\\` with the symbol `\`. The second is the so called escape character, that makes the compiler ignore the next character in your code.

So if you want to use some special characters in a String, like `\` or `"` you have to write `\\` or `\"`. The second one would let the compiler close the String.

This is why

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2016.1.2\include"\"\"\"\"
```

is transformed to

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2016.1.2\include""""""
```

The compiler (or preprocessor?) thinks that you open a String at the first `"` and escapes the following (invalid) characters.

---

It would be easier to see the mistake, if you posted the braking code.

Comment: Don't want to sound like a jerk, but please re-read my thread: I know "\" is the escape character, and the error I posted is not in code, but in the way Visual Studio decided to resolve the environmental variable I set in my System settings. :)

Comment: How exactly do you set you environment variable? This: `$(FBXSDK_DIR) = C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2016.1.2\` looks like a broken pointer.

Comment: Right click on Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> New...
It's not broken, it's perfectly functional on every other solution. In what way does it look broken?

Comment: If you were using the expression in my comment above (in a script or something similar) you would overwrite a copy of the value in `FBXSDK_DIR` with yours. Maybe you have a `"` somewhere it should not be? You could try to check your solution file manually with a text editor. Sometimes Visual Studio messes with it.

Comment: Oh, you misunderstand. "$(FBXSDK_DIR) = C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX SDK\2016.1.2\" is not the actual implementation code, I just wrote that to explain how the variable is called and to what it (usually) resolves to; the variable name is actually just `FBXSDK_DIR`. I did not add any further setting in Visual Studio beside putting $(FBXSDK_DIR) in the inclusions.